# How to trigger a method based on a Voice Command in UWP?

Tags: c#, windows-runtime, uwp

I want to trigger a method when a UWP app is running in foreground.
But the problem I'm having is the Speech Recognition works only when initiated from a button click type of event.

But I want to initiate this Speech Recognition when the user says a particular keyword.
Eg:"Alexa : Turn on the fan", Alexa being the keyword here.

And the app should be able to listen to this keyword through out its lifetime.

I haven't found any examples like these.
Can anyone point me in the right direction.

Comment: Cortana should be able trigger that, sample is [here](https://github.com/Microsoft/Windows-universal-samples/tree/master/Samples/CortanaVoiceCommand)

Comment: But I would like to have my own device name not Cortana, since I have my own AI running.

Comment: How you record your voice command?

Comment: Currently I'm having an infinite loop of SpeechRecognizer with the name "Alexa" running and once it triggers this it starts listening via a different Recognizer and decode the speech to text and this is parsed to my AI to get the response and do the required task.